# Java application locks up after playing sound

Tags: audio, java, freeze

Our Java application plays short notification sounds periodically (in response to user actions). On some hardward, our application will lock up after the 3rd or 4th short sound. We have to `pkill java` to recover.

We have the application installed on around 40 computers. All are running Linux. Half have Kubuntu 12.04 installed, half have Linux Mint 11 installed. All the Linux Mint 11 machines work fine and the Java app plays sound without locking up.

Initially (from the release of 12.04) all the Kubuntu machines also worked fine.

At some point, after an update, the Kubuntu machines started locking up when sound was played. If we turn off the sound notification option in our application, that is a workaround. The app will not lock up. But users want the sound.

When we discovered the problem, we stopped running updates on the Kubuntu machines and all those without updates (from months ago) continue to play sound from our app without the app freezing.

Even on the updated Kubuntu machines, lock up problem does not occur on all hardware. For example, on a Thinkpad X220 tablet, sound in our app works without problems. But on a ThinkPad E430, enabling sound in our app causes our app to freeze.

We cannot discover the pattern. What is causing the lockups on a recent Linux and some hardware while the older Linux is fine on all hardware we use?

Here's the info on some hardware where we **do have** the problem:

```
uname -a
Linux mynetbook-AO532h 3.2.0-41-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 25 03:27:11 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
################################################################################
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
################################################################################
aplay --list-devices
Home directory /home/myuser not ours.
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC272X Analog [ALC272X Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Pro [Sound Blaster X-Fi Go! Pro], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
################################################################################
aplay --version
aplay: version 1.0.25 by Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>
################################################################################
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0x58200000 irq 44
 1 [Pro            ]: USB-Audio - Sound Blaster X-Fi Go! Pro
                      Creative Technology Ltd Sound Blaster X-Fi Go! Pro at usb-0000:00:1d.1-1, full 
################################################################################
hwinfo --sound
process 2393: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL || !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c line 282.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
11: PCI 1b.0: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: u1Nb.ZCVQnTUjxO7
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1b.0
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel 82801G (ICH7 Family) High Definition Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x27d8 "82801G (ICH7 Family) High Definition Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1025 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0349 
  Revision: 0x02
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0x58200000-0x58203fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 44 (262 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d000027D8sv00001025sd00000349bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
################################################################################
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
joydev                 17693  0 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
bluetooth             180153  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
acer_wmi               28418  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 acer_wmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224173  1 
snd_hda_intel          33719  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_usb_audio         122982  2 
snd_pcm                97275  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              17764  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib        29476  1 snd_usb_audio
arc4                   12529  2 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
cp210x                 21898  0 
usbserial              47077  1 cp210x
ath9k                 132428  0 
uvcvideo               72627  0 
psmouse                97485  0 
snd_seq                61929  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
mac80211              506862  1 ath9k
serio_raw              13211  0 
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
ath9k_common           14053  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              411239  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
ath                    24067  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
cfg80211              205774  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
snd                    79041  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_pcm,snd_hwdep,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
mac_hid                13253  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 47238  0 
hid                    99636  1 usbhid
i915                  477763  3 
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
drm                   241971  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
atl1c                  41718  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
wmi                    19256  1 acer_wmi
video                  19651  1 i915
################################################################################
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
################################################################################
cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
################################################################################
lspci -vvx
[snip]
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0349
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 44
    Region 0: Memory at 58200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee0300c  Data: 4179
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v1) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed unknown, Width x0, ASPM unknown, Latency L0 <64ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed unknown, Width x0, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=1 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=80
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [130 v1] Root Complex Link
        Desc:   PortNumber=0f ComponentID=02 EltType=Config
        Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=02 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
            Addr:   00000000fed1c000
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00: 86 80 d8 27 06 04 10 00 02 00 03 04 10 00 00 00
10: 04 00 20 58 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 10 49 03
30: 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
[snip]
```

Here's a similar report for a machine that **does not** exhibit the problem:

```
uname -a
Linux netbook-Gate 3.2.0-41-generic-pae #66-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 25 03:50:20 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
################################################################################
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
################################################################################
aplay --list-devices
Home directory /home/me not ours.
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel ICH6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], device 4: Intel ICH - IEC958 [Intel ICH6 - IEC958]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Pro [Sound Blaster X-Fi Go! Pro], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
################################################################################
aplay --version
aplay: version 1.0.25 by Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>
################################################################################
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ICH6           ]: ICH4 - Intel ICH6
                      Intel ICH6 with Cx20468-31 at irq 21
 1 [Pro            ]: USB-Audio - Sound Blaster X-Fi Go! Pro
                      Creative Technology Ltd Sound Blaster X-Fi Go! Pro at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1, full 
################################################################################
hwinfo --sound
process 2510: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL || !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c line 282.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
18: PCI 1e.2: 0401 Multimedia audio controller
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: r0Vg.2VcHkXp8YSA
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.2
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1e.2
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x266e "82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x107b "Gateway 2000"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0365 
  Revision: 0x04
  Driver: "snd_intel8x0"
  Driver Modules: "snd_intel8x0"
  I/O Ports: 0x1c00-0x1cff (rw)
  I/O Ports: 0x18c0-0x18ff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xb0040800-0xb00409ff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xb0040400-0xb00404ff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 21 (58 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000266Esv0000107Bsd00000365bc04sc01i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_intel8x0 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_intel8x0"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
################################################################################
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
michael_mic            12540  4 
arc4                   12473  2 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17275  1 
lib80211_crypt_ccmp    12789  1 
rfcomm                 38139  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
bluetooth             158479  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32114  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
snd_usb_audio         101566  2 
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib        24588  1 snd_usb_audio
joydev                 17393  0 
snd_intel8x0           33455  2 
snd_ac97_codec        110213  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus               12642  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_usb_audio,snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
pcmcia                 39826  0 
snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
cp210x                 21610  0 
psmouse                86520  0 
ipw2200               146241  0 
libipw                 46732  1 ipw2200
tifm_7xx1              12937  0 
cfg80211              178877  2 ipw2200,libipw
usbserial              37173  1 cp210x
tifm_core              15040  1 tifm_7xx1
snd                    62218  18 snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
yenta_socket           27465  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            18367  1 yenta_socket
soundcore              14635  1 snd
pcmcia_core            21511  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,pcmcia_rsrc
lib80211               14040  4 lib80211_crypt_tkip,lib80211_crypt_ccmp,ipw2200,libipw
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
mac_hid                13077  0 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 41937  0 
hid                    77428  1 usbhid
i915                  423564  2 
firewire_ohci          40172  0 
sdhci_pci              18324  0 
firewire_core          56940  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12627  1 firewire_core
sdhci                  28241  1 sdhci_pci
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
drm                   197641  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  19115  1 i915
sky2                   53628  0 
################################################################################
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
################################################################################
cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
################################################################################
lspci -vvx

00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0365
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 21
    Region 0: I/O ports at 1c00 [size=256]
    Region 1: I/O ports at 18c0 [size=64]
    Region 2: Memory at b0040800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Region 3: Memory at b0040400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0
    Kernel modules: snd-intel8x0
00: 86 80 6e 26 07 00 90 02 04 00 01 04 00 00 00 00
10: 01 1c 00 00 c1 18 00 00 00 08 04 b0 00 04 04 b0
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7b 10 65 03
30: 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get the same output above from one of the systems that hasn't been allowed to upgrade yet, but still has functioning sound? Due to the differences in hardware it a little apples to oranges comparison of what you've provided so far.

Comment: @slm I don't have two reports like that for identical hardware where one (updated) fails and the other (not updated) works. We **were** in the process of gathering all that info. Each machine is at a different location and the operators have to grant us remote access. Time consuming.

Comment: @slm I came up with a workaround: don't use Java sound at all. I decided to make a system call and execute a shell command to play notification sounds via `mplayer`. It works in all situations we have tested. Our software only runs on Linux anyway, so maybe this isn't so bad... ?

Comment: If it works it works. I have a system with that ICH6 chipset that uses that same `snd_intel8x0` kernel driver and it's always been a pain. Feel free to post back if you're interested in pursuing this. What method were you playing the sound before you switched to mplayer?

Comment: I previously obtained the best results for playing sound in Java on Linux with the sun.audio.AudioStream and sun.audio.AudioPlayer. Those are "internal" classes and not recommended, but they worked better than anything else for me (for many years). Until the problem that prompted this question. My new solution is just this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mediaPlayerCommand + fileName);`

Comment: If I stick with the shell exec method, I probably need to optimize it. I have not looked into that yet. But it can get called very often and very frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously obtained the best results for playing sound in Java on Linux with the sun.audio.AudioStream and sun.audio.AudioPlayer. Those are "internal" classes and not recommended, but they worked better than anything else for me (for many years). Until the problem that prompted this question.

My new solution is just this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mediaPlayerCommand + fileName);`

For the media player, I can use `play` on OpenSuse or `mplayer` on Ubuntu. I just place that command in my configuration file on the target OS and it works really well.